# How can i use if condition inside for loop in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I used if condition inside for loop. I'm trying to display messages if condition is satisfied, condition is not satisfied don't want to display. Help me.

views.py

```
username = request.session['username']
sent_msg = Message.objects.filter(sender= username).values()
for i in sent_msg:
    print(i.sender)
    print(i.message)
return render(request, 'mes.html',{'sent_msg': sent_msg})
```

mes.html

```
{% for i in sent_msg %}
   {% if i.action_view == 0 %}
        <p>{{ i.sender }}</p>
        <p>{{ i.recipient }}</p>
        <p>{{ i.message }}</p>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here i'm trying to display data when if condition satisfied, otherwise it display nothing.
I tried in this way but its not displaying anything.

Comment: use double curly braces around `i.sender` and other fields, like this. `{{ i.sender }}`

Comment: Oops its my bad sorry i didn't noticed.

Comment: @NalinDobhal I corrected that error but its getting same thing not displaying anything.

Comment: What is the `action_view` field? Show the model definition. What do you get if you put `{{ i.action_view }}` before the if block?

Comment: This is not displaying the message because the condition is not satisfied.What is the value of `{{i.action_view}}`

Comment: @Satvik you need to add your model definition and what is the count of the objects in this query `Message.objects.filter(sender= username).values()`?

Answer (score 1):

The `for` in jija shuld be closed with a `{% endfor %}`.

```
{% for i in sent_msg %}
   {% if i.action_view == 0 %}
        <p>i.sender</p>
        <p>i.recipient</p>
        <p>i.message</p>
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i corrected that error but its getting same thing not displaying anything.